# Excel search value from whatever row and if found on another row replace that row with the value in the first row

Tags: excel, merge

What I am Trying to do is 
lets say I have a excel sheet with

rows

## ProductNo |  Product    |   Sku    |  Price |    Image   |  Thumb

25         | Shirt Blue  |   4251   |   $10  |  shirt.jpg |  shirtthumb.jpg

2          | Shirt Green |   4581   |   $17  |  green.jpg |  greenthumb.jpg

8          | Shirt Black |   4561   |   $15  |  black.jpg |  blackthumb.jpg

and just in different rows or on another excel sheet

## ProductNo   |    Product     |     Sku    |  Price  |    Image   |  Thumb

25           |    Shirt Blue  |    4251    |   $52   |            |
2            |    Shirt Green |    4581    |   $42   |            |
8            |    Shirt Black |    4561    |   $65   |            |

How can i change the first table to update if the the second table or sheet columns data is different on specified columns and if the cells are empty forget about them ignore them and just replace the values from the second table onto the first

Final would be

## ProductNo   |    Product     |     Sku    |  Price  |    Image   |  Thumb

25           |    Shirt Blue  |    4251    |   $52   |  shirt.jpg |  shirtthumb.jpg

2            |    Shirt Green |    4581    |   $42   |  green.jpg |  greenthumb.jpg

8            |    Shirt Black |    4561    |   $65   |  black.jpg |  blackthumb.jpg

I have tried a couple of excel functions but they do not work since i have so many products to be doing cell additions

I tried doing in Vl but got confused and macro i dont even know what it is

Im open to whatever visual, functions just as long as i can perform the task

if anybody know hos let me know

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

in stead of having the fixed values I propose you use a permanent formula in the specified columns.

Now to do this I would use a `VLOOKUP()` function. I am assuming that your ProductNo is the element that never changes therefore all the other columns will get a `VLOOKUP()` function.

Now if I understand correctly you MIGHT have an update in the 2nd table for the 1st table, but any empty cells in the 2nd table should be ignored.

I am also assuming you wish to see when an element will change because of the update therefore I propose the following:

In the first table add for the block of columns elements that might need an update: 2 blocks of columns, the first with the result of combining (the *COMB-block*) and the second with lookups from the 2nd table (the *LOOKUP-block*). For convenience of explaining I put the two tables in the same workbook on the sheets called *table1* and *table2*

**ProductNo | Product | Sku | Price | Image | Thumb | Product_comb | Sku_comb | Price_comb | Image_comb | Thumb_comb | Product_lookup | Sku_lookup | Price_lookup | Image_lookup | Thumb_lookup**

Now start with formulas in the *LOOKUP-block*, use `VLOOKUP()`, such as this one for the *Product_vlookup* column:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,table2!$A:B,COLUMNS(table2!$A:B),FALSE),"")`
The IFERROR is for the case the product in table1 cannot be found in table2

For the formulas in the *COMB-block* the following will prefer the table 2 result over the table 1 result. As `VLOOKUP` of a matching ProductNo with an empty Element (for example for the Image) will result in a 0 (zero) returned all zeroes are regarded false lookup results as well. This is the script for the *Product_comb* column:
`=IF(OR(ISBLANK(L2),L2=0),B2,L2)`

As a final step to identify the products that changed you can either add a column that compared the original value with the _comb value:
`=AND(B2=G2,C2=H2,D2=I2,E2=J2,F2=K2)` (this returns true for no changed columns and false for any changed column)
Or use conditional formatting on each element separately or on the combination as the `AND()` formula shows.

As a final step in your process of updating you could copy all records from the *COMB-block* and paste it over the original elements.

If you have any further questions please ask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , im going to have to read it over a bit then try it out vloopfunction im not familiar with it but let me read up on it and ill be back , Thanks